# xslt - how to convert iso Alpha 2 code to Country name

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml which has the two char alpha code which need to be converted into a fully qualified country name. For example, DE should become Germany. I understand that xslt templates can be used to keep the list within xslt to fetch the relevant names however I am not happy with that design and am looking for an xslt function (or something similar) which will avoid any future maintenance of the mapping. please let me know your thought on this. thanks.

Comment: You could put the mapping list in a standalone XML document and lookup from there.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot add the standalone xml to the server so I am looking for something like a rest api. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps call a web service e.g. with XSLT 3 you can process the JSON returned from most REST APIs

```
  <xsl:template match="code">
    <country>{json-doc('https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/' || .)?name}</country>
  </xsl:template>
```

For XSLT 2 you could use a service returning an XML format e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="code">
    <country>
       <xsl:value-of
         select="doc(concat('https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/', .))/countries/country/name"
         xpath-default-namespace="http://www.worldbank.org"/>
    </country>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @martin honnen but unfortunately I cannot use the xslt 3 at this point due to other dependency. Do you know of any 2.0 version of the solution?

Comment: @Sudesh, whether you want to use XSLT 2 or 3 doesn't really matter as long as you have a web service you can access and it gives you a format you can process, the first I googled returns JSON so I used an XSLT/XPath 3 feature to process that JSON but I would think you can find another service that returns XML you can read in XSLT/XPath 2 with the `doc` function and then select an attribute or element in the returned XML that has the name with XPath (and in XSLT use e.g. `xsl:value-of select="doc(concat('http://example.com/country/', .))//name"/>` . But search for such a service yourself.